# How do I find the last item in a js loop so I can add a class to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to build a list. No problem.

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    $('#domid').append(variable.clone());
}
```

How do I get the LAST item in the list (in this case i.7) and add a class to it?

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    $('#domid').append(variable.clone());

    if (i===7) {
        $('.domclass').addClass('last');
    };

}
```

But that won't work. That just makes all of the .todo items have the class when the counter get's to 7.

Any suggestions on how to find this?

Thanks!

Comment: Doing DOM queries within loops is the recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.domclass:last').addClass('last');
```

Or, if you'd like to do it in the loop (so, as the commenter pointed out, you don't have to traverse the DOM to get to the element again):

```
var newElement;

for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    newElement = variable.clone();
    $('#domid').append(newElement);
    if(i === 6) {
        $(newElement).addClass('last');
    }
}
```

Comment: @DaveMerwin - No worries. It happens. Also remember that there's no need to use it inside of a loop. It's just a single call after you build your elements.

Comment: @JustinNiessner Instead of doing a DOM query for that element subsequently, it would have made more sense to add the class right after creating that element. It's like writing a letter, sending it out, and then retrieving it back in order to add the signature.

Answer (score 1):

`i` never equals `7` because the loop runs while `i < 7`

Answer (score 0):

`eq()` with a negative index count backward.

```
$('.domclass:eq(-1)');
```

http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is within the loop store a reference to the cloned item:

```
var i,
    $item,
    $domid = $('#domid');

for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    $item = variable.clone();
    $domid.append($item);
}

$item.addClass('last');
```

When the loop ends `$item` will be the last one added. Of course this assumes the loop will always run for at least one iteration - if the number of iterations is variable and might be zero you could say:

```
if ($item) $item.addClass('last');
```

(Note that I'm also storing a reference to the `#domid` element rather than reselecting it on every iteration.)

Comment: Look at Justin Niessner's answer.  Let's use the tools we're given.

Comment: @Madbreaks - I think a downvote is a little harsh given my answer is not actually wrong. Obviously Justin's answer is a simple way to do it, and I had already upvoted his answer. But the question did not make it clear whether there might be other elements with the ".domclass" class, and my answer would work specifically on the newly added elements, and also it avoids creating extra jQuery objects (which admittedly doesn't really matter at all in this simple example but in a more complex situation might help with performance).

Comment: @Madbreaks This answer is clearly better than Justin's answer.

Comment: Fair enough, downvote removed. I think you're right, too harsh. But generally we as developers should use the tools we're given instead of reinventing the wheel, unless there are limiting performance issues involved. There a boundless ways to solve a given problem, but generally the best approach is not only the one that arrives at a correct answer, it's also the most efficient.

Comment: Thanks @Madbreaks. For this problem I don't have a strong preference either way, but "efficient" could be applied to the effort to write (and later read) the code _or_ to the performance at runtime...

Answer (score 0):

This his how I would do it:

```
var $domid = $( '#domid' );

for ( var i = 0; i < 7; i+= 1 ) {
    $domid.append( variable.clone() );
}

$domid.children( ':last' ).addClass( 'last' );
```